# Laravel 9 API works with localhost but not with device IP

Tags: php, laravel, apache, multi-tenant, htdocs

I have my Laravel 9 installed inside xampp/htdocs. It works fine when I use API URL with localhost but it throws 404 when I use my device's IP address.

`http://localhost/myapp/public/api/users` It works fine and returns me all the users

but

`http://192.168.254.6/myapp/public/api/users` gives me 404. Due to this I am not able to access the app from local network too.

I simply tested the case with only one php file `test.php` and `http://192.168.254.6/testapp/test.php` works fine.

I logged the incoming requests in index.php inside Laravel public directory and I found that Laravel is receiving the requests but when I tried to log the requests inside a controller and even inside a middleware, I got nothing.

What might be the reason for it?

Comment: How did you set up the environment? Is incoming connection open for the port where the Laravel app is running?

Comment: you need to define v-hosts for that

Comment: @rkg As I have my project inside xampp/htdocs, I am accessing it via port 80 that is default http port for apache. Also, if it's a problem related to port then it shouldn't have been accessible via `http://localhost..` too.

Comment: @AqibJaved As far as I know, the Apache v-hosts are used to handle multiple host names or IP addressed directed towards a single Apache server. But I am accessing my application inside a directory. If there really is the need for virtual hosts, then how am I able to access another simple directory with single php file without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research, I found the solution. The issue was due to a package configuration file `config/tenancy.php` of https://tenancyforlaravel.com/

The old configuration was:

```
    /**
     * The list of domains hosting your central app.
     *
     * Only relevant if you're using the domain or subdomain identification middleware.
     */
    'central_domains' => [
        '127.0.0.1',
        'localhost',
    ],
```

Adding the specific local IP or a blank string fixed the issue:

```
    /**
     * The list of domains hosting your central app.
     *
     * Only relevant if you're using the domain or subdomain identification middleware.
     */
    'central_domains' => [
        '127.0.0.1',
        'localhost',
        ''
    ],
```

As stated in the code comments, this config should have been only valid while using domain or subdomain but I was using request data to identify tenant, still it was causing the issue.